# Debug Error Stack Around Variable Was Corrupted

Tags: c++

I am an amateur at programming and have been running into an error that says "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'store' was corrupted." I have looked up this error before but I don't see any fix that applies to what I am trying to do. It seems like this error can occur for a variety of reasons.

My code does exactly what I want it to do but I don't understand why it gives this error and I would really appreciate it if somebody could explain this to me. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int store[4] = {};

   for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
   {

      cout << "Enter the sales of store " << (i + 1) << ": ";
      cin >> store[i];
   }

   cout << "\nSALES BAR GRAPH\n(Each * represents $100)\n";

   for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
   {
      int a = (store[i] / 100);
      cout << "\nStore " << (i + 1) << ": ";
         for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
         {
            cout << "*";
         }
   }

   cout << "\n";

   system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is incorrect:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
```

This references `store[4]`, which is out of bounds if you declared `int store [4]`. If you want to keep store size as 4, you should change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```